# C# delegate for function with no return value and one parameter that allows sub type classes (as parameter)

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates, covariance, contravariance

I'm looking for a delegate that encapsulates a method that return no value and take one parameter, like **Action< T >** does, but unfortunately that delegate does not match with method taking a **child type** as parameter...

That's what I'm trying to do:

```
public class BaseType
{
    public BaseType()
    {

    }
}
public class ChildType : BaseType
{
    public ChildType()
    {

    }
}
public class Test
{

public delegate void CallBackHandler(BaseType p);

    public Test()
    {
        CallBackHandler clbk1 = callBackA;
        CallBackHandler clbk2 = callBackB;   //That line does not compile
                                             //->'No overload for 'callBackB' matches delegate 'Test.CallBackHandler'
    }

    private void callBackA(BaseType p)
    {

    }

    private void callBackB(ChildType p)
    {

    }
}
```

I read about covariance, contravariance, etc... I know it deals with the herited type casting but I'm a little bit confused about all of this...

Which delegate should I use to make my code work ?

Comment: Possible solution: `CallBackHandler clbk2 = p => callBackB(p);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic type safety problem that strong typing was created to solve.

Here's an example

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    public virtual void MethodSlot1_StartEngine() { }

    public virtual void MethodSlot2_StopEngine() { }
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public virtual void MethodSlot3_OpenGasTank() { }
}

class NuclearSubmarine : Vehicle
{
    public virtual void MethodSlot3_FireAllNuclearMissiles() { }
}

class VehicleUser
{
    public delegate void OpenGasTankMethod(Car car);

    public void OpenGasTank(Vehicle vehicle, OpenGasTankMethod method)
    {
        //it's stopping you here from firing all nuclear weapons
        //by mistaking your car's gas tank for the armageddon switch
        method(vehicle); 
    }
}
```

When the compiler emits a virtual method call it just compiles an index into a lookup table.  If you could pass in a NuclearSubmarine where a Car is required merely because they are both Vehicles, then you could think you are calling Car methods (like opening your gas tank) when in fact you are just making the *Fallout* series of games a reality.

In response to your comment, this should get you started:

```
class Blah
{
    private List<Action<object>> _handlers = new List<Action<object>>();

    public void AddListener<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        //graceful type checking code goes in here somewhere
        _handlers.Add(o => handler((T) o));
    }

    void RaiseEvent(object eventArgs)
    {
        foreach (var handler in _handlers) handler(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the logic of that... I'm actually trying to implement a custom event system that looks like the JavaScript/AS3 one, with a addEventListener(MyEventName, myCallbackMethod) registering method that could pass any handling method that takes an Event, ***or an herited type of Event***, as parameter.
I assume it's not possible... : (
Thx for your answers

Comment: @LePioo - One more suggestion - you may want to wrap the event handlers you are given into your own wrapper handler that checks to make sure the type is what the user's handler was expecting before calling it, or else wrap the call of the user handler in a try to catch the InvalidCastException when the types are wrong (though this is less efficient that storing the Type data for the parameters somewhere and checking Type.IsAssignableFrom(argument.GetType());

Comment: @LePioo - I have updated my answer to give starter code for your use case.

Comment: @LePioo - if you want the ability to remove a listener, it's a bit more complicated, but that would make a great question for SO :)

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look at your edit (though I'm not aware of the o => operation ^^ I know where to look now)

Comment: Hi LePioo - the o=> isn't important, it was just to demonstrate the concept of wrapping the usercode handler in your own handler.  You won't be able to support removing handlers if you use the lambda expression ("o => ") so you can skip learning that for now.  It's really useful though so come back to it later :)

Comment: I've been able to do it following your advise! Thanks a lot!
I've posted a new question though, but which could be related, if you wanna take a look at it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998702/c-sharp-skip-generic-type-declaration-with-inference
thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this since it is not safe. If it were allowed you could do:

```
class OtherChild : BaseType { }

CallBackHandler clbk2 = callBackB;
clbk2(new OtherChild());
```

and pass an instance of `OtherChild` to a delegate which requires an instance of `ChildType`. Note that the following is safe and compiles:

```
public delegate void CallBackHandler(ChildType p);

CallBackHandler clbk1 = callBackA;
CallBackHandler clbk2 = callBackB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the delegate as

```
public delegate void CallBackHandler(ChildType p)
```

If the handler could accept and should act on instances of `BaseType`, what would happen if you passed in an instance of a new class `NewChildType`? Nobody knows, which is the reason why you can't here.